# How to solve ts2339? Using typescript with testing-library/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got an error message " Property 'toggled' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339) "

Strangely, My test case all have succeeded.
But, In testing file, There have occured error message about ts.2339.

What shall I do to solve this problem?

```
component...
<Container data-testid={"list-element-toggle"} toggled={state[data.id - 1]}>.  * style.div``
  <Content data-testid={"list-element-content"} toggled={state[data.id - 1]}>. * style.div``
...

testing file...
expect(getAllByTestId("list-element-toggle")[0].toggled).toEqual(true);
expect(getAllByTestId("list-element-content")[0].toggled).toEqual(true);
```

- I think of it had been occured why the toggle has other HTML DOM Element.
  So, I had this trouble.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what the type of the zeroth item in the result of calling getAllByTestId is. But also why test the value of the prop, the *implementation* rather than the behaviour that setting that prop causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved-self my problem
the 'toggle' has a html dom element. but, I want to fire for specific button was in other place.

I had selected the button for test, it solved it

Answer (score 1):

testing-library/react is not checking the props of the component.
Probably you should have a logic inside `Container` and `Content` that is based on `toggled` prop.

For example inside `Content`:

```
export function Content({ toggled }) {
  return (
    <div>
    {toggled ? : <p>I am toggled</p> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then in the test:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

render(<App />);
expect(screen.getByText("I am toggled")).toBeInTheDocument();
```